# how to implement file search functionality?

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, lucene

I am working on file search engine functionality.I need your suggestions in designing my application.
I am using elastisearch as framework to implement my functionality.

My primary feature is to enable file search based on file name , file type, size and date of creation. I also need to enable searching based on content of file.

Please suggest what can be best possible file to do the indexing and extract file data.

Also since file can be deleted/updated so i would need to generate the index again in some time interval so how can i monitor any change in directory.

I am using SAMBA as my file storage system.

Answer (score 1):

To have the search option in file content you need to index the file into elasticsearch index.

Look in to the [Mapper Attachment](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments#mapper-attachments-type-for-elasticsearch) plugin and this will help you to index the files and make it searchable.

***Step01:*** install the plugin in to your elasticsearch cluster

***Step02:*** convert the files as byte[] and sent it to elasticsearch index

***Step03:*** Now you can search using the file content using normal queries.

**Note:** This will work only for text based files like pdf, word (doc,docx) & text files. if the pdf files contains text in images it will not be searchable.

Comment: I installed the Mapper Attachment plugin. I am following the steps mentioned in the below URL to test the functionality once. http://www.elasticsearch.cn/tutorials/2011/07/18/attachment-type-in-action.html  <br/> I am able to create the index but my search functionality is not working. When i run the below URL - <br/> curl "localhost:9200/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
  "fields" : ["title"],
  "query" : {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "amplifier"
    }
  },
  "highlight" : {
    "fields" : {
      "file" : {}
    }
  }
}'  <br/>  this returns me total hits as 0.

Comment: Could you please move your code to git hub and provide me the URL so that i can test the same and tell you the reasons...